# Running Cassandra with an incomplete ring

Tags: cassandra

We have a total of four data centers with fully meshed communication, except two data centers are (and will be) unable to directly talk to each other due to network restrictions. Is there any way in Cassandra to deal with this type of situation by excluding connectivity between these sites, while replicating through the other data centers and still keeping the cluster consistent?

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a way to tell the Cassandra clusters to only make use of your IP lists and not use their auto-discover feature. In that case I would imagine that you could accomplish what you are asking here.

Comment: Thanks!  Anyone have a more detailed explanation on how to do this or a guide in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a page with the information:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html

> [cassandra] auto_node_discovery
>
> Enables or disables auto-discovery of nodes. When disabled, OpsCenter only attempts to contact nodes in the seed list, and will not auto-discover nodes. By default this is True.

Obviously that means you have to make sure to remember that you have to manually identify all the nodes as you add new ones to your cluster.